# Safest approach for holding an instance of Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-context

What is the **best and safer approach** for holding an `instance` of the `Activity`

```
private Activity mActivity;
```

***First*** approach:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mActivity = getActivity();
}
```

***Second*** approach:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    mActivity = (Activity) view.getContext();

    return view;
}
```

Comment: By saying `If you do not have chance to used getActivity();` what exactly do you mean? In `Fragments` we can always use `getActivity()` in `OnCreate()` but we also can use `view.getContext();` in `onCreateView()`. In this case which will be safer?

Comment: As per my aspect `getActivity();` safer becoz you use it `onAttach()` mean to say your `context` is available suddenly after you attach `Fragment` to your `Activity` while `view.getContext();` is only available after `onCreateView(....)`

Comment: @MD Yeap, that makes sense, thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends. I would advice you to use `getActivity()`.

You can use it after [`onAttach(Activity activity)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)). If you look at the `FragmentManager` source code, you can see there, that the `mActivity` field of `Fragment` is set just before calling `onAttach`.

But you have to be careful, the activity is not fully initialized (views,..) before `onActivityCreated` gets called.

Answer (score -1):

In most cases, you should not need to catch Activity. 
But if you want to, my suggestion is,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity = this; 
}
```